# How to fail deployment with AWS ECS if service fails to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, deployment, amazon-ecs

I am deploying an API service (FastAPI) with AWS ECS using the following in `azure-pipelines.yml`:

`aws ecs update-service --region "myRegion" --force-new-deployment --service myAPI --cluster arn:aws:ecs:xxxxx:cluster/myClusterName`

If the API fails to start for whatever reason (e.g. broken code), the above command will roll back to the previous stable API state as per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html), without any sort of alert. Is there a way to make the pipeline job/deployment fail and exit 1 if the service/API fails to start properly, instead of rolling back? Ideally without using CloudWatch.

I have tried `--deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=true,rollback=false}"` as per docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-circuit-breaker.html), but there seems to be no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws ecs update-service` command does not wait for the ECS deployment to complete. This command tells AWS ECS to make some updates to your deployed service, and then it exits. The actual deployment in ECS takes several more minutes. And if the deployment fails and is retried several times before the deployment circuit breaker kicks in, it could actually take a long time.

If you want your pipeline to wait for the ECS service to be fully deployed, and throw an error if the deployment fails, then you need to run [another command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/wait/) after `aws ecs update-service` is done. That command is:

```
aws ecs wait services-stable --region "myRegion" --service myAPI --cluster arn:aws:ecs:xxxxx:cluster/myClusterName
```